# Вывод дерева в шаблон html

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

Всем привет, как вывести дерево в html, начал пользоваться treebeard в django,
сообственно сама модель:

```
from treebeard.mp_tree import MP_Node

class Category(MP_Node):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'category'
        verbose_name = 'Категорию'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'


    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name='Имя категории')

    node_order_by = ['category_name']


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Category : %s" %self.category_name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

и вьюха

```
def c2(request):
    category = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'store/c2.html', {'category' : category})
```

то есть тут как бы все правильно, просто помогите все это вывести в html

Comment: А можно увидеть ваш шаблон?

Comment: Шаблон кривой, вот именно что я не могу выстроить, но когда передаешь allcategory в цикле есть такие параметры как depth(глубина), numchild, category_name, id(Пример cat.depth == 1) только не совсем понимаю как с помощью циклов, списков и с этими параметрами выстроить дерево в html, либо скорее всего придется свой template tag писать

Comment: Связанный вопрос [How to generate an html directory list using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10961378/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому нибудь понадобится, все же решился написать фильтр и вроде получилось, извините если неправильно задан был вопрос изначально.
Пришлось поработать с api самого treebeard и написать рекурсивную функцию.

```
    @register.filter(is_safe=True, name='render_grass')
    def render_grass(category, n):

        result = "<ul>\n"

        for cat in category:

            if cat.depth == n:
                result += '<li>\n<span><a href =' + reverse('products',
                                                    args=[cat.id]) + '>' + cat.category_name + '</a></span>\n'

                childrens = cat.get_children()

                if childrens:
                    result += render_grass(childrens, n + 1)

            result += '</li>\n'

        result += '</ul>'

        return mark_safe(result)
```

Если хотите можете доработать и оставить здесь.